# vue неограниченное количество вложенных компонентов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

проблема заключается в следующем.

есть вот такое начало https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-hofstadter-49g45?file=/src/App.vue

после нажатия на "Добавить" появляется список. по нажатию на "+" в списке появляется еще один item-списка, который будет лежать в массиве info первого объекта главного массива items . и таких образом вложенностей может быть неограниченное количество.

возможно ли реализация через динамические компоненты? так как изначально нет данных о количество вложенностей. создать шаблон динамического компонента и создаваться он будет всегда если длинна массива info>1.
если так нельзя то подскажите способ реализации данной задачи.
если же можно через динамические компоненты , то просьба поделиться на инфу. гуглить что то не очень получается. спасибо

Comment: можно увидеть структуру данных по которым нужно строить вложенность, задача не сложная, я делал что-то подобное на React,  но это можено реализовать на чем угодно, общая суть компонент содержит в себе список компонентов таких же как он сам - все это отрисовывается рекурсивно

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html

подобное Вы можете найти в документации Vue.js.

Отличие только в том, что Вам по тригеру кнопки в айтеме нужно будет добавлять для элемента, где был совершен клик, данные в массив info, чтобы дерево верно отрисовывалось.

Comment: у Вас кстати список на дивах весь. Вы планировали сделать под него виртуализацию?